# Ruby Mongo gem bulk insert of enumerable

Tags: ruby, mongodb, twitter, performance, enumerable

I am using ruby 1.9.3 with the twitter and mongo gems.

I have the following code working:

```
Twitter.user_timeline("GSElevator", :count => 200, :exclude_replies => "true", :include_rts => "false").each do |r| rawtest.insert(r.attrs) end
```

My currently method of looping through each enumerable and then inserting the attrs, one by one, proves to be relatively slow. 
How can I insert the 200 enumerables in a single, quick batch?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an array of documents to the [`insert`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#insert-instance_method) method:

```
rawtest.insert(Twitter.user_timeline("GSElevator", params).map(&:attrs))
```